# How to query Wikidata (SPARQL) by official website property P856?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

How can you search the Wikidata SPARQL query service for a record whose official website (property P856) matches a specific value?

For example, fetch all records whose official website is "https://www.google.com". This should return Q95 and Q9366, but instead the following query yields no results:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE  {
    ?entity wdt:P856 "https://www.google.com"
}
```

I can get it to work with a FILTER, but it's very slow:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE  {
    ?entity wdt:P856 ?url FILTER(str(?url)="https://www.google.com")
}
```

Using FILTER seems very inefficient. Why doesn't the first query work?

Comment: It is not a literal but a RDF resource URI: `?entity wdt:P856 <https://www.google.com>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [the values you get](https://query.wikidata.org/embed.html#SELECT%20%3Fentity%20%3Furl%0AWHERE%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fentity%20wdt%3AP856%20%3Furl%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%2025) from [this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fentity%20%3Furl%0AWHERE%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fentity%20wdt%3AP856%20%3Furl%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%2025) --

```
SELECT ?entity ?value
WHERE 
  {
    ?entity wdt:P856 ?value
  }
LIMIT 25
```

Note that they're all wrapped in `<>`, marking them as URIs. To compare a URI with a string literal, you must change the URI to a string, as you are doing in the second query.

In other words -- there are no entities with an official website of `"https://www.google.com"`, but there are some entities with an official website of `<https://www.google.com>`.

Comment: In fact, not absolutely all; add `FILTER(!isURI(?url))`; there will be 25 results :-).

Comment: @StanislavKralin - Technically true. Crowd-sourced and -curated data is both good and bad, and almost always messy. Still, I think strings like `t189022293` (which resembles all 87 non-URI results found after also removing the `LIMIT` clause) do not satisfy either the letter nor the intent of the OP's question.